# Django: sqlite3 failes to find the path of sqlite file

Tags: python, django, sqlite, pycharm

```
Connection to Django default failed.
path to 'C:\Users\nblizz\Workspace\Files\myweb\Web\db.sqlite3': 'C:\Users\nblizz\Workspace\Files\myweb' does not exist
```

I changed project name from `myweb` to **pyweb**, but Django's sqlite3 still recognizes the path of `.sqlite` file as `myweb`. So above error message keeps appear in PyCharm's database console.

I modified all of `myweb` in `settings.py` and `manage.py` but nothing has changed. How to I fix the path of `.sqlite` files of Django?

**settings.py:**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: @9769953 I'm using development server. I've restarted server 3~4 times but the error still occurs.

Comment: @9769953 `print(BASE_DIR)` gives me correct path: `C:\Users\nblizz\Workspace\Files\pyweb\Web`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was PyCharm's data source problem.

You can change the file path by `Right-click on DB name -> Properties -> Modify path of 'file'`.